# Create new user via tenderapp api

Tags: .net-3.5

Wondering if you can help. I'm using c# on the .net 3.5 framework. Where I'm attempting to create a user via the tenderapp api. On each attempt I get a 'The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity. '.

I'm using the following code:

```
string username = "Eddie";
string password = "password";
string tenderUrl = string.Format("https://{0}:{1}@api.tenderapp.com/sitekey/users", username, password);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(tenderUrl);
request.Accept = "application/vnd.tender-v1+json";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";
string postData =  "{'email':'***@eddie.com','password':'test','password_confirmation':'test'}";


byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();//error returned here

Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Not sure if the postData string is causing the error.  For further info please see https://help.tenderapp.com/kb/api/users

Would be greatful if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Eddie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working. The password for creating a new user needs to be at least characters. Tidied things up a little, but here is the working code.

```
public void createTenderUser(string supportUser, string supportPassword, string userEmail, string userPassword)
{

    //Throw argument exceptions 

    string tenderUrl = string.Format("https://{0}:{1}@api.tenderapp.com/iremoco/users/", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(supportUser), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(supportPassword));
    string postData = string.Format("{{'email':'{0}','password':'{1}','password_confirmation':'{1}'}}", userEmail, userPassword);
    if (userPassword.Length >= 6)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(tenderUrl);
            request.Accept = "application/vnd.tender-v1+json";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch
        {
            //display error
        }
    }
    else { 
        //display error
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Eddie